# How to make a base class for both Page and UserControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

Base classes for Page and UserControl:

```
public class MyWebPage : System.Web.UI.Page { }

public class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl { }
```

Helper that either of them might use:

```
void SetSessionValue<T>(string key, T value) { Session[key] = value; }
```

How can I achieve something like the following?

```
public class WebObject // can't inherit from both Page and UserControl { 
   protected void SetSessionValue<T>(string key, T value) { 
      Session[key] = value; 
   }
}  

public class MyWebPage : WebObject { }

public class MyUserControl : WebObject { }
```

Update: I got excited for a second hoping I could solve it this way, but alas it doesn't compile.

```
public class WebObject<T> : T
{
}
public class MyWebPage : WebObject<System.Web.UI.Page>
{
}
```

Comment: How many methods like this will you have, and how much code will be in each method?  Why not just duplicate the code?  This one-liner seems way to short to worry about this.  Also, if `Page` and `UserControl` have any common base class, you could simply make an extension method on that type.  E.g. on `System.Web.UI.Control` or `System.Web.UI.TemplateControl` - you could only do this if you didn't need state from your custom base class tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Not easily anyway. I'd recommend just creating a base class for pages and user controls, and duplicating the common code in both. Since user controls are contained in pages, you can also delegate methods in the base user control class to the base page class simply by casting the `Page` property to your own type:

```
// Code in the MyUserControlBase class
public int SomeCommonMethod() {
    return ((MyBasePageType)this.Page).SomeCommonMethod();
}
```

You can also make your life miserable by creating an interface implemented by both base classes and using DI to intercept method and property accessor calls, which would then be routed to some kind of common surrogate class that actually provides the implementation. I probably wouldn't go there :)

Comment: i ended up making a Context class that gets created by the base page, and putting a get property accessor on the control base using the pattern described in your snippet here - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC both Page and UserControl inherit from [TemplateControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.TemplateControl%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) so you might be able to inherit from that.

Comment: Yes I was looking at that.  Note that the Session property is not in the TemplateControl class.  If it were then he'd just need to add an extension method to TemplateControl.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid duplication is to have a helper class, instantiated through a static property and accessible from anywhere in your UI (Page, UserControl or any other classes in the UI tier).

Something like:

```
public class ApplicationContext
{
    // Private constructor to prevent instantiation except through Current property.
    private ApplicationContext() {}

    public static ApplicationContext Current
    {
        get
        {
            ApplicationContext current = 
                 HttpContext.Current.Items["AppContext"] as ApplicationContext;
            if (current = null)
            {
                current = new ApplicationContext();
                HttpContext.Current.Items["AppContext"] = current;
            }
            return current;
        }
    }

    public void SetSessionValue<T>(string key, T value) 
    { 
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value; 
    }
    ... etc  ... 
}
```

A single ApplicationContext instance will live for the lifetime of the current request, and you can use `ApplicationContext.Current.SetSessionValue` and other common members from anywhere in your UI tier code.

I often go further than putting general-purpose methods like your `SetSessionValue` in such a helper class, and might have application specific properties in there, e.g.

```
public class ApplicationContext
{
    ... as above ...

    public ShoppingBasket ShoppingBasket
    {
        ShoppingBasket shoppingBasket = 
           HttpContext.Current.Session["Basket"] as ShoppingBasket;
        if (shoppingBasket == null)
        {
            shoppingBasket = ... e.g. retrieve from database
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Basket"] = shoppingBasket;
        }
        return shoppingBasket;
    }
}
```

In this way you can access the current `ShoppingBasket` instance anywhere in your UI without knowing or caring that it's cached in Session - that's an implementation detail known only to your `ApplicationContext` class.

Answer (score 0):

- 1) Make a static class that has all the variables, functions you need
- 2) Make your own UserControl and Page class, and make these classes
  call your static functions in the Pre_Init and Load overrides
- 3) Make every page inherit your base classes.

That's the easiest way.

Comment: Not a good idea I think. Static classes are the enemy of dependency injection and do not allow you to make mocks for easy testing. They are also singletons which might not work well. If you want a helper class that both classes use; create a normal class that is the implementation of an interface and inject the interface into the places you need it on construction of those objects. That way you can mock it out all you wish for easy testing and you don't end up with statics littering your code and making it harder to test.